Issue compiling YugabyteDB
Issue: Compilation Failed
I have attached the CMakeError.log file.
Yugabyte Version: 2.14.11
System Info:
OS - Ubuntu22.04
Architecture: x86_64
Cmake error log:
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-qPjEXQ

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_389a8 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
clang version 15.0.7 (https://github.com/yugabyte/llvm-project.git 6b9d30d80f5cebc66c9fa46013d18f125ea8ec0e)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 (in-process)
 "/opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin/clang-15" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-qPjEXQ -resource-dir /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7 -dependency-file CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o.d -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -sys-header-deps -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-qPjEXQ -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -x c++ /home/teja/tools/cmake-3.25.2-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
clang -cc1 version 15.0.7 based upon LLVM 15.0.7 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++
 /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_389a8
FAILED: cmTC_389a8 
: && /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build-support/compiler-wrappers/c++  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -o cmTC_389a8   && :

( cd "/home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-qPjEXQ" && YB_THIRDPARTY_DIR=/opt/yb-build/thirdparty/yugabyte-db-thirdparty-v20230803170310-057e0a1188-centos7-x86_64-clang15 /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin/clang++ -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -o cmTC_389a8 )  # Compiler exit code: 1.

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| COMPILATION FAILED
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clang version 15.0.7 (https://github.com/yugabyte/llvm-project.git 6b9d30d80f5cebc66c9fa46013d18f125ea8ec0e)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTC_389a8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/clang_rt.crtbegin.o -L/opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin/../lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libclang_rt.builtins.a -lc /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libclang_rt.builtins.a /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/lib/clang/15.0.7/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/clang_rt.crtend.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Input files:
  /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-qPjEXQ/CMakeFiles/cmTC_389a8.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
Output file (from -o): cmTC_389a8
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.




Determining if the C++ compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-PkZm8A

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_e3f6a && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f6a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_e3f6a
FAILED: cmTC_e3f6a 
: && /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build-support/compiler-wrappers/c++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f6a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_e3f6a   && :

( cd "/home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-PkZm8A" && YB_THIRDPARTY_DIR=/opt/yb-build/thirdparty/yugabyte-db-thirdparty-v20230803170310-057e0a1188-centos7-x86_64-clang15 /opt/yb-build/llvm/yb-llvm-v15.0.7-yb-1-1680628984-6b9d30d8-ubuntu22.04-x86_64/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f6a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_e3f6a )  # Compiler exit code: 1.

/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| COMPILATION FAILED
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Input files:
  /home/teja/Opensource/yugabyte-db/build/release-clang15-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-PkZm8A/CMakeFiles/cmTC_e3f6a.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
Output file (from -o): cmTC_e3f6a
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Make sure you install the requirements and it should work:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
packages=(
  autoconf
  build-essential
  curl
  gettext
  git
  locales
  ninja-build
  pkg-config
  libstdc++-12-dev
  rsync
)
sudo apt install -y "${packages[@]}"
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

